# Linker error in Codelite with MinGW-w64

Tags: mingw-w64, codelite

I'm trying to use MinGW-W64 instead of MinGW in Codelite. When I compile simple "hello, world" project it's all right. But when I try to link some libraries, I get a strange linker error. Project with exactly same settings compiles by MinGW with any problems. There are build output for both variants:

MinGW GCC 4.8.1

```
`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C D:/apps/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ code - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Projects/codelite/code'
codelite-cc D:/apps/mingw/bin/g++.exe  -c  "D:/Projects/codelite/code/src/main.cpp" -Wfatal-errors -g -O0 -pedantic -W -std=c++11 -Wall  -o ./Debug/src_main.cpp.o -I./inc/
D:/apps/mingw/bin/g++.exe -o bin/code @"code.txt" -L./lib/  -lopengl32
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Projects/codelite/code'
====0 errors, 0 warnings====`
```

MinGW-W64 GCC 5.2.0

```
`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C D:/apps/mingw-w64/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ code - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Projects/codelite/code'
codelite-cc D:/apps/mingw-w64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe  -c  "D:/Projects/codelite/code/src/main.cpp" -Wfatal-errors -g -O0 -pedantic -W -std=c++11 -Wall  -o ./Debug/src_main.cpp.o -I./inc/
D:/apps/mingw-w64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -o bin/code @"code.txt" -L./lib/  -lopengl32
g++.exe: error: @code.txt -L./lib/: No such file or directory
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [bin/code] Error 1
code.mk:78: recipe for target 'bin/code' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Projects/codelite/code'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 0 warnings====`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in your toolchain and not in CodeLite.
There is a space between the `"@code.text"` and `-L./lib` and for some reason `g++` does not see it...

I put my money on the `mingw32-make` tool. You can tell CodeLite to use the `mingw32-make.exe` from the 4.8.1 version (which worked): `settings->build settings->compilers->[YOUR COMPILER NAME]->Make`

Another option is to disable the option that tells CodeLite to generate `Makefile` that passes the object list via file to the compiler:

`Settings->Build Settings->compilers->[YOUR COMPILER NAME]->Advanced tab` and uncheck the option: **pass object list to the linker via file**

Comment: The first approach resolved this problem. Thank you very much! I want try second one but can't find this option in settings. I use Codelite version 9.0.0

Comment: Your solution is not correct because it is the  permissions

Answer (score 0):

Lately i too have found the similar problem. Later i was able to figure out the issue. We just to need to go to the project settings under change makefile generator default to codelite makefile generator i think that will work.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was:

- Right-click on Project
- Setting/General
- Change Makefile Generator to Default