# Linker issues with msys2 mingw64 package library (libserialport) in Codelite - undefined reference

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, msys2, codelite

I am running some very simple experiments with the [libserialport](http://sigrok.org/api/libserialport/unstable/index.html) library installed through [msys2](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-libserialport?repo=mingw64) however, I run into linking problems no matter what configuration I set in the project settings. I am compiling with the latest version of gcc 13.2 from msys2.

[image: linking issues]

I have confirmed that the library files are in the correct directories:

`C:\msys64\mingw64\lib` : libserialport.a

`C:\msys64\mingw64\include`: libserialport.h

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`: libserialport-0.dll

I surely might be missing something obvious for more experienced ones.

[Note] I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544658/linker-error-in-codelite-with-mingw-w64) post, however, changing the Makefile generator to just "Make" or Codelite's does not work (compilation gets stuck. Maybe I am doing something really wrong :/ )

:beers:

As I mentioned, I have tried multiple combinations of settings (these aren't the only ones I tried. I have pointed at the dll, made the linking `-static`, etc.):

[image: compiler settings]
[image: linker settings]

Additionally, my environment variables point at the right folders from the `mingw64` location (hence why other projects work fine)

Please note that my Codelite works flawlessly with other projects. Additionally, my msys2 system is up to date and other contributed libraries work well (not all of them tested but no linking problems so far).

In case it works, I am testing with the `list_ports.c` [example](http://sigrok.org/api/libserialport/unstable/a00002.html) from their wiki page:

```
#include <libserialport.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* Example of how to get a list of serial ports on the system.
 *
 * This example file is released to the public domain. */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        /* A pointer to a null-terminated array of pointers to
         * struct sp_port, which will contain the ports found.*/
        struct sp_port **port_list;
        printf("Getting port list.\n");
        /* Call sp_list_ports() to get the ports. The port_list
         * pointer will be updated to refer to the array created. */
        enum sp_return result = sp_list_ports(&port_list);
        if (result != SP_OK) {
                printf("sp_list_ports() failed!\n");
                return -1;
        }
        /* Iterate through the ports. When port_list[i] is NULL
         * this indicates the end of the list. */
        int i;
        for (i = 0; port_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
                struct sp_port *port = port_list[i];
                /* Get the name of the port. */
                char *port_name = sp_get_port_name(port);
                printf("Found port: %s\n", port_name);
        }
        printf("Found %d ports.\n", i);
        printf("Freeing port list.\n");
        /* Free the array created by sp_list_ports(). */
        sp_free_port_list(port_list);
        /* Note that this will also free all the sp_port structures
         * it points to. If you want to keep one of them (e.g. to
         * use that port in the rest of your program), take a copy
         * of it first using sp_copy_port(). */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove those `-LC:\msys64\...` flags. If you're using the correct compiler, those directories will be searched automatically. If you get an error after doing that, you're not using the compiler you're supposed to.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, as I mentioned, I tried that at first and it does not work. I still have linking issues: "undefined reference to `sp_list_ports`, `sp_get_port_name`, `sp_free_ports_list`". Any other ideas? Cheers

Comment: Where did you mention that? Not seeing it. Try compiling directly from the MSYS2 terminal, to make sure CodeLite isn't doing anything weird. If it doesn't work, please add the command you used and the error messages to the question (as text).

Comment: You don't list any libraries.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat on top of the second screenshot it reads: "_As I mentioned, I have tried multiple combinations of settings (these aren't the only ones I tried. I have pointed at the dll, made the linking -static, etc.):_". Good advice, I will try to compile through the console

Comment: *"You don't list any libraries."* Now I feel dumb. You need `-lserialport`.

Comment: @stark holy cow! You might have found my solution. Could you please post an answer to _potentially_ mark it as a solution? I do not have linker issues....

Comment: @HolyBlackCat now, the BIG question that I have is why with other projects I do not need to include them in the linker list of libraries. Perhaps the configuration for other projects is different? :S

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you know who feels ACTUALLY dumb? The one who is typing this! stark got it. That was the solution ffs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Ok, guys. There is a little thing that I just found out regarding the `Makefile Generator` setting in CodeLite. I will post an answer shortly explaining this. This _might_ be a bug in CodeLite

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stark for finding the right solution for me. I simply had to include the library in the linker. Dumb me.

As I mentioned in my last comment, I noticed there apparently was a *bug* in CodeLite, however, I can't replicate it anymore ¬¬ (Murphy's Law?)

The non-repeatable *bug* consisted of the following:

Despite adding the reference to the library in the linker options: `-llibserialport`, the linking stage would still fail. Changing the `Makefile Generator` setting from  `CodeLite Makefile Generator` to `Default` *magically* made my errors disappear and the program built and ran just fine.

[image: successful execution]

Then, reverting the setting back to `CodeLite Makefile Generator` and after cleaning the project the code built and ran again without any problems.

From now on, I believe that I will select the `Default` Generator for all my projects as it seems to work from the get-go.